# Last sentence of company president's speech: translate or not to translate

Tags: translation

For example, Japanese correspondence has several set phrases and sentences, which are important, but at the same time they are usually omitted when translated into other languages.

Here I have the company president's speech or rather written comment. And these are the last two sentences:

> 以上｛いじょう｝、当社｛とうしゃ｝の明るい｛あかるい｝未来｛みらい｝が見える｛みえる｝まで、共に｛ともに｝頑張って｛がんばって｝いきたいと思って｛おもって｝います。よろしくお願い｛ねがい｝致します｛いたします｝。

1. Should I translate these two sentences? If yes, could you tell me, which way would be the best?
2. I wonder if I have to translate the word 以上?
3. I wonder if I have to translate the phrase よろしくお願い致します?

Comment: 願い is read ねがい, not いねがい; I've corrected it for you.

Comment: A brief comment regarding #3: I think the last sentence is asking the listeners to please help out with the mission the speaker has just described. So I would use something like "I hope you will all work together with me to make this company the best it can be". However, this is just one possible idea, and I won't claim it is the "best" way. Making a very appropriate translation might require more information about the company, the speaker, and other factors. But this should give you something to think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try something in the "corporate style".

> 以上、当社の明るい未来が見えるまで、共に頑張っていきたいと思っています。よろしくお願い致します。

[With the above in mind,] I am looking forward to working side by side with you to [achieve/improve] our future [prospects/outlook].

Remarks:

- The translation of 以上 here depends on the previous content to get something natural in English.
- The translation of 「よろしくお願い致します」depends on the president's manner and reputation.

  - If they're a real "straight shooter", you could use something like "Now let's get out there and put our backs into it".
  - If they're fairly dull, something more generic like "Thank you again for all of your continuing efforts" is an appropriate equivalent formulaic.
- The issue with 「〜まで」 is I think mostly with the different connotations in English.

  English "until" is a limiting word that expresses an "upper bound", as in, "I'll stay here until you fall asleep." In English, this strictly implies that the speaker won't stay any longer. I don't think this is the case in Japanese.

  This is similar to the use of 「だけ」, which, while often translated as "only", has the same problem: "only" in English includes an upper bound, but 「だけ」 expresses a lower bound. This is why 「できるだけ、やってみましょう」 is not a negative phrase in Japanese as a literal translation would make it in English.

  Thus, 「〜まで」 here seems more indicative of the president's expressed willingness to see through their stated goals for the company. At any rate, it's complicated to try and work all of this into a translation that fits into one or two short words, so don't break your back over it.

Answer (score 3):

1: "For the bright future of (this/our) company let's do our best together. I’m really looking forward to working with you."

2:Really depends on you, I don't think it makes a great difference.

3: Translate "よろしくお願い致します". Even though it can't be directly and absolutely translated, do translate it, because it carries a lot of meaning. I think anyone who knows even a bit Japanese understands that.

It's not an actual per word translation but I think it gets the message across just fine.

You might not like my suggestion and that's ok,  but I insist on translating よろしくお願い致します.

Comment: By the way, what is the use of "まで" here? I would expect "ように". It seems to strange for it to mean "until"

Comment: About "まで", I don't know... But it is written in the original Japanese text. Anyway, I agree, that it sounds a little bit strange. Maybe it is author's small mistake.

Comment: Tasos Anesiadis, just wanted to say, thank you for your kind contribution on my question!